# Second invocation of Aspectj-adviced method in is ignored

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am in the process of adding some *AspectJ* advices in my *Spring*-based Java project. When I run an intercepted method once, it all works fine (i.e., the advice is executed). However, the next invocation of the very same method does not go through the proxy anymore.

This is my test code:

```
@Test
public void testFooOperationIsAdviced() throws Exception {
    TestController testController = appContext.getBean("testController");
    testController.foo();
    testController.foo();
}
```

Here's the `foo()` method:

```
@Protect()
public void foo() {
    System.err.println("foo!")
}
```

And this is the relevant part in my Spring configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean name="myAdvice" class="mypackage.MyAdvice"/>

<bean id="testController" class="mypackage.MyTestControllerImpl" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="protectAspect" ref="myAdvice">
        <aop:pointcut id="annotatedController" expression="execution(public * mypackage.*+.*(..)) and @annotation(protect)" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="annotatedController" method="applyProtectionRules" arg-names="protect"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

The aspect is currently just doing `System.err.println("advice")` and `pp.proceed()`.

So, if we execute the test above, you'd expect

> advice
>   foo!
>   advice
>   foo!

However, what I get is:

> advice
>   foo!

The second invocation never gets to the advice! And, what is worse, *the target method is not even executed*.

Do you have any clue as to why this happens?

Note 1: To make things worse: sometimes, when I execute with the debugger and go step by step, it does work normally. No kidding...

Note 2: If there are typos in the config, they are just typos, since I adapted the original code to make it simpler. Take into account that the aspect does work for the first invocation.

Note 3: I do want to stick to Spring. I can't have the pointcuts hardcoded in the Java code, since I want the library user to provide their own, and the only way I can think of is let them define the `aop:config` block.

Comment: Can it be that the first call to `testController.foo();` causes an exception?

Comment: No, it's not that (as you can see in the accepted answer), but it was a good guess, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the 2-kilometer-long stack trace, I saw a `CachingInterceptor`... That's the solution to the mystery: our custom caching mechanism, based on a Spring method interceptor, was doing the trick. It has a timeout of 120 seconds, and that's why the execution seemed fine when I used the debugger.

I won't close my (admittedly dumb) question in case it helps others. A bit of perspective and thinking out of the box would've helped!

Comment: In two days, SO will allow me to accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: It happens, thanks for posting the solution and admitting the error.